# Postgresql : Getting specific field from Data Value

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way to get the get the specific values from date such as year , month , day . 
Actually we have in php date function . If we give  date (Y-m ) ; it will give us 2010-07 . 
I want like this in postgres(psql) .

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'MM')
FROM v_use_doc_line
;`

This will provide you with the month value of the `CURRENT_DATE`. If you need year, just replace `MM` with `YYYY`.

I hope you can guess now what you should do to get the day :).

For further information, see the [to_char](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-formatting.html) function of postgresql.

Comment: And link to the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-formatting.html

Comment: Use YYYY and MM: SELECT to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY MM');